# onChange event does not trigger upon date selection

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, onchange, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap 4 in my react js. I just simply link the bootstrap datepicker in my `index.html` like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html className="no-js" lang="zxx">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/assets/img/favicon.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And display in my react component like this

```
<div class="input-group date mb-3" data-provide="datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" onChange={e => console.log(e)} />
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text"><i className="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

When selecting the day from the calendar, it doesn't fire the `onChange` event. I didn't use react datepicker plugin because they have issue with the calendar display. That's why I continue using from the bootstrap datepicker link.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data-provide="datepicker"` from the div and add it in your input element